# Truncate title to single line & container width

Tags: php, content-width

Is there a way to truncate a title to the container width? I'm able to do truncate a long title to one line using the code below, but that doesn't really work for mobile.

```
<h3>
    <?php
        $thetitle = $post->post_title;
        $getlength = strlen($thetitle);
        $thelength = 33;
        echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
        if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "...";
    ?>
</h3>
```

Comment: Not with PHP. PHP executes on teh server and has no idea how the page gets rendered.

Answer (score 1):

how about using CSS3's "text-overflow:ellipsis;" ?

doing so will make sure your title stays in a single line, trimming whatever crossed the container's width limit.

Comment: It works, but you also have to add "white-space: nowrap;" and "overflow; hidden;". Thanks.

Comment: err... yeah... I'm sorry.
I carelessly thought most people already know how to use it.